Inconsistent result with calling lambda's in list with called list of lambda's in list in python
The problem is that I expect the following three lists to be the same when called, but l2 and l3 are equal to each other, l1 is different
l1 = [(lambda: j) for j in range(2)]
l2= [lambda:0, lambda: 1]
l3 = [(lambda: j)() for j in range(2)]
print(l1)
print(l2)
print(l1[0]())
print(l2[0]())
print("l3: ", l3)

Also, when I print out l1 and l2 (not called), I get the exact same list of lambda object, but they are different when called. What is happening?

Cannot reproduce for l1 I get [<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x10367ed40>, <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x10367ede0>] and printing l2 gives [<function <lambda> at 0x10367ef20>, <function <lambda> at 0x10367efc0>]

Also, can you please provide your actual output.

I assume what you mean is that you expect l1[0]() to return 0 rather than 1, because j had a value of 0 at the time that the lambda was put into the list. It does not work this way, and this is an extremely commonly asked about issue. Please see the linked duplicate.

l1 = [(lambda: j) for j in range(2)]

Here j is a captured variable within the scope of the list comprehension, so it's "alive" for both iterations of the comprehension loop and when that loop is finished, j equals 1, so both lambdas will return the same value j (i.e. 1).

l2 = [lambda: 0, lambda: 1]

Here there are two lambdas with concrete return values. Nothing interesting or tricky going on here.

l3 = [(lambda: j)() for j in range(2)]

Here you're constructing and calling a lambda on each comprehension iteration so you aren't storing the value of j directly, but the return value of the lambda. That's why this code doesn't "remember" the last value of j like the l1 example.

this is because of lazy evaluation
in first case l1 = [(lambda: j) for j in range(2)]  The lambdas in the list comprehension are a closure over the scope of this comprehension. A lexical closure, so they refer to the iteration via reference, and not its value when they were evaluated! more info
in 2nd and 3rd case,  result is determistic and function is called as soon as it made, so it evaluated immediately
